# How to open a custom editor from an Action in Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse-che

I am going to create a extension in Eclipse Che. I want the users to open a editor from the top menu. In order to do this, I read the instruction from this link 'https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/parts'. But it only shows how to create each part of the UI around a editor. It supports four positions as shown below:

```
EDITING: area just above the editor, like a file tab
NAVIGATION: area on the left to project explorer
TOOLING: area to the right of the editor
INFORMATION: area under the editor, 'console' area
```

I also read the editor tutorial from 'https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/code-editors' but the editor has to associate with a file type. 
Is there a way to open a Editor without a file type? Such as open it from an action in a menu.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?